# Forcing video to take up entire width of SImpleExoPlayerView

Tags: android, android-layout, logic, media-player, exoplayer

I'm having trouble forcing a video to be the entire width of a `SimpleExoPlayerView`. I've read through a couple stack overflow posts and have not been successful. The layout:

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/video_framelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
    android:id="@+id/post_videoView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

I also tried using the following java code:

```
            postVideoView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);
            postVideoView.getPlayer().setVideoScalingMode(MediaCodec.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_SCALE_TO_FIT_WITH_CROPPING);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to manually reset the resize_mode:

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/video_framelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/post_videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:resize_mode="fixed_width"/>

</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.AspectRatioFrameLayout>
```